# Touch corner rectangle using sprite kit in swift. The code will run, but no rectangle appears

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to add a rectangle with a corner where the user first touches, and with its other corner where the user lifts off. I would also like the rectangle to show while the user is dragging their finger.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
        let position1 = touch.location(in: self)
        var x1 = position1.x
        var y1 = position1.y


        func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
        let position2 = touch.location(in: self)
        var x2 = position2.x
        var y2 = position2.y

        var originX = min(x1,x2)
        var originY = min(y1,y2)
        var cornerX = max(x1,x2)
        var cornerY = max(y1,y2)
        var rect_width = cornerX - originX
        var rect_height = cornerY - originY

        var rect_con = CGRect(x: originX, y:originY, width: rect_width, height: rect_height)

        var box = SKShapeNode(rect: rect_con)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First up, if you're only after a rectangle, you're better off doing this with just a SKSpriteNode, and scaling it, with this:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skspritenode/1645445-scale

Secondly, for future reference, SKShapeNode is a half (or less) complete conversion of CAShapeLayer into a VERY primitive drawing tool. It's not good at dynamic drawing, at all.

---

Set the anchor point of the SKSpriteNode rectangle at the touch point, and scale to the x and y of the touchesMoved. You might have to do a bit of conversion for negative values, since this is operating from an origin in cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me that your `touchesEnded` function is declared from within the `touchesStart` function and because of that is not visible from the class scope and then never gets called.  It should look more like this (not tested):

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
for touch in touches{
    let position1 = touch.location(in: self)
    var x1 = position1.x
    var y1 = position1.y
    }
}

func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{
    let position2 = touch.location(in: self)
    var x2 = position2.x
    var y2 = position2.y

    var originX = min(x1,x2)
    var originY = min(y1,y2)
    var cornerX = max(x1,x2)
    var cornerY = max(y1,y2)
    var rect_width = cornerX - originX
    var rect_height = cornerY - originY

    var rect_con = CGRect(x: originX, y:originY, width: rect_width, height: rect_height)

    var box = SKShapeNode(rect: rect_con)
}
}
```